# Understanding interaction between Apple Watch and iPhone device

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, watchkit, handoff

I am a bit confused as when I run the Apple Watch extension App schema on the simulator I see only that the Apple Watch app gets lunched. However I am not sure what will happen with **real hardware** once we get our hands on the Apple Watch.

I'd like to understand the following:

1. Do I need to start the corresponding iPhone App on the phone before
   starting the App on the Apple Watch?
2. If the answer to 1 is no then, can I
   start an iPhone App from the App on the Apple Watch? If the answer to 2
   is yes then how can I start the iPhone App in a way that is not in
   the background? (I found handleWatchKitExtensionRequest can trigger
   background tasks but I haven't found any documentation yet for
   that - I also found the **Handoff Api** which allows you to resume a task on the device but I don't like that it requires an iCloud account and I am not sure how to structure an App/watch interaction **without forcing the user to adopt iCloud**).
3. Given that the Apple Watch App extension resides on the iPhone App
   bundle does this mean that when you start the Apple Watch App it needs a
   connection and **proximity** with the iPhone device? I assume that there will
   be a bluetooth connection and that it won't be possible to start
   some apps if the user and its watch are away from the Iphone (what's
   the range?)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. No.
3. Unless you are on a Wifi network recognized by both your Watch and your iPhone, they'll need to be relatively close to each other. Guessing at range is useless – a number of factors can impact the useable distance of BTLE.

Comment: But let's say I want to create an Apple Watch app that runs when the watch is AWAY from the iPhone... so that user can input little pieces of data using the watch and the watch can manipulate that data, store it and present some UI... is that possible?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Third-party Watch apps rely on the iPhone at this time.